# How do I PERMANENTLY DISABLE a power management option for a wireless adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, wireless-adapter

So I recently got a new custom built Dell Optiplex 9010 Desktop computer on windows 10 pro that didn't come with a wifi adapter so I got one myself, a TP-Link Wireless MU-MIMO USB Adapter as it shows in adapter options. Problem is, I have turned off "Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power" in power management but it isn't permanent. Every time I restart my computer it re-enables so when I have large steam downloads going overnight the adapter decides to shut off completely and I'm not able to turn it back on unless I do a full network reset which is really annoying.

Is there any way to permanently disable this option? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your power settings for suspending usb devices? 
A good walkthrough is here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-prevent-windows-10-turning-usb-devices

Comment: Thanks, I've disabled it so I'll see if it helped. This isn't quite making the option permanent though, will this do the same thing?